# How to pass host ip address to docker in mac OS?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, docker

I am working on Linux machine and I wrote an script to pass local host IP address to docker container by passing an parameter It works fine for ubuntu.
will the same script run on mac OS and work as expected (pass IP address of local host to docker container)?

```
docker run -t -i -e "DOCKER_HOST=$(ip -4 addr show eth0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+')" $IMAGE_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

On OSX use this command line:

```
docker run -it -e "DOCKER_HOST=$(ifconfig en0 | awk '/ *inet /{print $2}')" $IMAGE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

On mac, you will be using a VM, so you might want to pass the IP of the docker machine you have declared:

[image: https://docs.docker.com/installation/images/mac_docker_host.svg]

<sup>(image from "[docker on Mac OS X](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/)")</sup>

```
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

Comment: in my team some member are using mac machine at some remote location. Exactly I don't know how they are using. I wrote a common script to run docker and pass local machine address to docker container. Just I want to confirm will it work for same or should i write another script?.

Comment: @PawanSharma It should work the same when executed on each member's mac.